# Deploy projeto Python no heroku com erro

Tags: python, django, heroku

Estou tentando fazer deploy de um projeto Python usando Django no Heroku. O deploy ocorre tudo bem, mas ao tentar fazer `heroku run python manage.py migrate` ocorre o seguinte erro.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
  execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
  utility.execute()
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 317, in execute
  settings.INSTALLED_APPS
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
  self._setup(name)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
  self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
  mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/app/djangosige/configs/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  from .settings import *
File "/app/djangosige/configs/settings.py", line 4, in <module>
  from .configs import DEFAULT_DATABASE_URL, DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD, EMAIL_PORT, EMAIL_USE_TLS
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'djangosige.configs.configs'
```

Esse é meu arquivo configs.py

```
# Configuração da base de dados

# Caso seja deixado vazio o default será: 'sqlite:////...djangosige/db.sqlite3'
DEFAULT_DATABASE_URL = 'postgres://meuuser:minhasenhadbc@localhost/nomebd'

# Configurações do servidor de email

# Endereço de email padrão utilizado

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'meu@email.com'

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'  # Gmail
# EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.live.com' #Hotmail

# Usuário do email padrão
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'meuuser'

# Senha do email padrão
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'minhasenha'

# Verificar a port utilizada pelo serviço de email
EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Alguém sabe o que pode estar ocorrendo?

Answer (score 0):

## Interpretando a mensagem de erro:

Voce tem o módulo:

```
/app/djangosige/configs/__init__.py
```

Na linha 3 desse arquivo voce faz um import

```
from .settings import *
```

Que é executado com sucesso, com o asterisco voce importa tudo de forma implicita, prática não recomendada pela PEP 20 (Explicit is better than implicit.), nesse import o arquivo `settings.py`é carregado e na sua linha 4 vc faz o import:

```
from .configs import DEFAULT_DATABASE_URL, DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,....
```

Ou seja, voce esta em `/app/djangosige/configs/`fazendo import do modulo config que não existe.
Por isso a mensagem de erro: `No module named 'djangosige.configs.configs'`

Answer (score 0):

Eu indicaria usar uma api para o postgresql **dj-database-url** e configura o servidor de email no mesmo diretamente no settings.
Para min nunca deu problemas!

```
import dj_database_url

    DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.config()
    }
```

EMAIL_BACKEND ='django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

```
EMAIL_HOST =""
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ""
EMAIL_PORT = 3386
EMAIL_USER_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ""
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = ""
```